# C# adding +5 to a datatable if criteria is met

Tags: c#

I am attempting to add  5 if a row contains a certain string and was looking for assistance.

> Example:

```
Col1|Col2
BKN | 1
PHL | 2
```

> on button click I would like it display as:

```
Col1|Col2
BKN | 6
PHL | 2
```

So far I have the following:

```
for (int i = csv_datatable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (csv_datatable.Rows[i][4].ToString() == "BKN")
    {
        decimal add = (Convert.ToDecimal(csv_datatable.Rows[i][6]) + 5);
        add++;
```

Thank You!

Comment: and whats your problem? what did you try?

Comment: I would suggest that you read up on how to use variables in regards to `add` also do not post partial code. I would also look at how to use a `foreach` when working with a datatable. familiarize yourself with how to use the debugger too.. also why are you looping from the bottom up ? there is a much better and more efficient way to do this as well

Comment: looks like you are mostly on the right track. (excep "add++").
What you need to do is save the result of your addition back to your datatable

Comment: assuming it is a typed datatable, try `csv_datatable.Rows[i][6] += 5`

Comment: Thank you @DaniDev .. that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for  (int i = csv_datatable.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (csv_datatable.Rows[i][4].ToString() == "BKN")
            {
                decimal add = (Convert.ToDecimal(csv_datatable.Rows[i][6]) + 5);

                csv_datatable.Rows[i][6] = add;

            }
```